# Read CSV file and only keep some lines according to values in list (Python)

Tags: python

I will reformulate the problem I had previously stated:

I am currently trying to only read about 26 million rows from a file that has about 600 million. I currently have a list with those 26 million rows that I am interested.

My solution is as follows:

```
## list_ is a list of indices with the number of the 26MM rows 

# First, open the output file where i want to copy the 26MM rows
with open(output_file,'w') as g:
# Open the source file with 600MM rows
  with open(source_file,'r') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
      if i in list_:
        g.write(line)
```

Given the size of the list and the size of the original file, I am afraid it might take too long to process this file. I am aware that this topic has been covered in other questions, but I don't think other posts have asked when the text files are very large.

Thank you and apologies for the previous confusing post,

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: It's just been going for a few hours now. I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this. I should probably describe better the problem that I'm facing and while looking for values in lists millions of times is the best I could come up with.

Comment: Try going one step back and describing the actual problem. Why do you need to check this list 600 million times? Are the elements completely random or is there some structure? Almost certainly there is a better way to do what you need.

Comment: Given how little information you've provided, the only thing I can suggest is that you convert the 26 million item list to a set. Checking if an item is in the set should be much faster.

Comment: Sorry guys, you are right. Let me rephrase the problem to provide more context.

Comment: I reformulated the question. I hope its clearer now what i try to do, apologies for the confusion

Comment: Use a set instead of a list.

Comment: using a set solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to check whether a value is in that list, the best time is O(1) for each check. You probably want to use hashset instead of a list. You can google hashset in python to see some example, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724002/contains-of-hashsetinteger-in-python) or see this doc, [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).